# Swift UIViewController UITableView editing mode causes tableView sections to return nil

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, swift, ios8

I have a UITableView that's working just fine.  When I enable editing mode using the following code inside of viewDidLoad() method:

```
self.tableView.editing = true
```

I get the following error:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

on this line:

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
      return fetchedResultsController.sections!.count // error here
 }
```

I checked and fetchedResultsController is NOT nil, but sections is.

This is not the case if editing mode is disabled.

What could be the cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To stop this particular error, you can simply return a default value in `numberOfSectionsInTableView` when `fetchedResultsController.sections` is `nil`:

Note the use of `sections?` instead of `sections!`, and the [Nil Coalescing Operator](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-XID_124) `??`:

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return fetchedResultsController.sections?.count ?? 0 // 0 is the default
}
```

That doesn't explain why your `fetchedResultsController` is returning a `nil` `sections` array when your `tableView` is in `editing` mode.

I suspect that `sections` might be `nil` because you're setting `editing` in `viewDidLoad` and that's triggering a table view reload. At that point, `fetchedResultsController` may not have had enough time to fetch any results at all so it doesn't have any `sections` to return. It's possible that simply returning a default of `0` when `sections` is `nil` will be enough since then `fetchedResultsController` will have time to finish its loading and reload the table view with the proper data.

Comment: Awesome, that solved my problem for now.  You're probably right about your assumption.  I'll mark it as correct for now.

Answer (score 0):

I thought the syntax was:

```
self.tableView.setEditing(true, animated: true)
```

I haven't modeled this in any code.  So if it doesn't help, let me know and I will try again.